# Dialing down the Bevel increment amount

Tags: bevel, settings

Holding the shift key when adjusting the value on bevels dials down the increments suitably for most objects, but there are some occasions when this just isn't enough. I  sometimes find myself making adjustments on the 0.001 value.

Without changing the measurement settings, is there anything I can enter into the value box of the bevel modifier or any keys I can press, that will dial the increments down even further?